# Powershell C# Commandlet not able to get DataTable when set from script side

Tags: c#, powershell, pipeline, powershell-cmdlet

I am having strange problem regarding usage of `DataTable` that is set from `Powershell` Script `Commandlet` to `C#`. I don't know why a properly constructed `DataTable` is being pushed as series of `DataTableRow` as data rather than fully packed `DataTable`. This is blocking me to process anything further. Below is C# `commandlet`.

```
[Cmdlet(VerbsCommon.Set, "LinkParameter")]
public class SetLinkParameter : PSCmdlet
{
    [Parameter(Position = 0)]
    public string ParameterName { get; set; }


    [Parameter(Position = 1, Mandatory = true, ValueFromPipeline = false)]

    public object ParameterValue { get; set; }

    protected override void ProcessRecord()
    {
        base.ProcessRecord();
        var setParameterValue = ParameterValue 

       // This never comes in proper DataTable format rather than appears as System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow System.Data.DataRow
        .............
        ............
    }
```

Above `System.Data.Row` would be equal to the amount of data rows contained in data table. I can't place `DataTable` as Parameter type because I have to set all standard data type values along with `DataTable` as well.

Below is `Powershell` script.

```
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable
$col1 = $table.Columns.Add( "Col1", [string]) 

$col2 = $table.Columns.Add( "Col2", [int]) 
$table.Rows.Add( "bar", 0 ) 
$table.Rows.Add( "beer", 1 ) 
$table.Rows.Add( "baz", 2 ) 

Set-LinkParameter "CreatedData" $table  
Set-LinkParameter "SetTestMessage" "testMessage"    // can also be set.
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What if you cast it to the DataTable type?
`public DataTable ParameterValue { get; set; }` and further down `var setParameterValue = (DataTable) ParameterValue`

Comment: Nops : I get exception. "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Management.Automation.PSObject' to type 'System.Data.DataTable'."

and the reason is it's transferred from Powershell script to C# commandlet side as PSObject rather than DataTable or object it self.

Comment: Moverover I can't replace ParameterValue data type as DataTable. Because this commandlet has to be used to transfer data of all primitive data types ( e.g. bool, string, int and floats )

Comment: The data types of a `DataTable` are listed in `$Table.Columns[0].DataType` and `$Table.Columns[1].DataType` and not in the `DataRow` records.

Comment: iRon : I didn't get the idea. Can you please let me know by modifying above piece of code. What to do and how it would work to have single command let operating for all data types including DataTable.

Comment: What is the exact symptom? What shows you that `ParameterValue` doesn't actually contain a `System.Data.DataTable` instance? Note that PowerShell implicitly enumerates a `System.Data.DataTable` instance in the pipeline (enumerates its rows). From what I can tell, `ParameterValue` is a `PSObject` instance whose `.BaseObject` contains the table.

Comment: Also, I suggest defining `ParameterValue` directly as `PSObject` rather than `object`. That way, the underlying object can be accessed consistently via `.BaseObject`.

Comment: Thanks mklement0. It was perfect. PSObject and finding inner BaseObject is the way to go for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mklement0 pointed out in comments. We can access PSObject internal BaseObject and there every thing would be contained.